# findIndex returning undefined instead of number

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
const index = myArray.findIndex(
      (f) =>
        f.name === term1 ||
        f.name === term2
    );
```

As I am trying to debug in Chrome Dev Tools, if I set a breakpoint after this snippet, `index` always shows as `undefined`. It was my understanding that `findIndex` should always return a `number`, the first index of the array where the condition is met, -1 if it is never met.

If I break immediately after this code and use the console to manually type in the code but don't assign it to anything, the console shows the correct index number. The issue isn't with the item being found in the array. It is there, but in the debugger it will only show undefined.

Why is this code returning `undefined` rather than a `number`?

*I have tried this in Firefox and Edge. It is the same issue there as well.

Comment: When you say that you set a breakpoint "after" that code, do you mean *immediately* after that code, as in the next statement after the `const` declaration?

Comment: Yes. I've tried breaking at several points in the code that follows the `const`. Any other variables I check on are correct, just not `index`

Comment: Sounds like you are not using the debugger correctly or you are looking at the evaluation value of the `const` statement which is always `undefined`. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/T8Dmkuw.png)

Comment: I am taking the result of `findIndex` and assigning it to a variable. Why would the value of that variable be `undefined` when I try to read it at a breakpoint? @MinusFour, it is not like the example. I am fully aware that the console will display undefined after the action. The value of the variable itself if undefined.

Comment: Declaration statements evaluate to `undefined`. To evaluate `const myVariable = somethingElse` would initiliaze `myVariable` and set it to `somethingElse` but it will evaluate to `undefined`. If you evaluate `myVariable` after that and it's `undefined` then yes `somethingElse` would be `undefined`.

Comment: At that point, the only one thing I can think of is a bad polyfill for `Array.prototype.findIndex`.

Comment: A couple of other explanations I can think of... You are using `Array.prototype.find` instead (that one does return `undefined`) or you aren't evaluating `index` after this statement and there's an `index` variable on a higher scope which is `undefined`.

Comment: Is the `index` used later on in your program code? If not, the variable might be optimised away. Also, are you using a transpiler? It might have renamed the variable and the debugger doesn't find the target name in the source map.

Comment: That might be it. I do reuse the `index` variable later to replace the item in the array at the specified index. The transpiler issue is a likely culprit.

Comment: @Bergi that was it the problem. If you want to post that as the answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding your code a bit I have :-

```
const term1 = 'aaa';
const term2 = 'bbb';
const myArray = [ { name: 'ccc' }, { name: 'ddd' }, ];
const index = myArray.findIndex(
  (f) =>
    f.name === term1 ||
    f.name === term2
);
console.log(index);
```

I always get the expected output of -1, or as expected.  I tried fiddling with various combinations and types - no go.

In my environment your code works fine - so I would guess the problem lies elsewhere.

Sorry - this doesn't constitute an answer - just some input :-)

Comment: I appreciate the input at least. What is strange is that can't seem to be able to debug the code. It has to be some issue surrounding that and not the code itself I imagine.